# How to avoid underfull boxes in itemize?

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, itemize

I am using an itemize as shown in this example:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{The First}\\
    Some text here over fifty lines.... bla blah
    \item \textbf{The Second}\\
    Other text here over multiple lines... bla blablaaah
    \item \textbf{...}\\
\end{itemize}
```

The results looks as expected for me. :-)  [image: Result]

But because of the `\\` I get some underfull box messages. I also tried to use `\newline` or `\linebreak` insted.

How to avoid these overfull box messages?

Comment: Never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph it can never do anything useful there,. So just delete (at least) the`\\ ` before `\end{itemize}` But probably you should delete all the `\\ `  and use `description` not `itemize` then `\item[The First] Some text....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `\\` out of tables, and never use it at the end of a paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline,format=--- \textbf]
\item[The first]
 Some text here over fifth lines\ldots{} bla blah

\item[The second]
Other text here over multiple lines\ldots{} bla blablaaah
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: but the text of the new paragraph is indented.  here you'd want an explicit `\noindent` for the first paragraph, because an indentation probably *is* wanted if the rest of the text for an item has multiple paragraphs.

Comment: @barbarabeeton no you wouldn't want a `\noindent` but you might want to set up more list parameters to specify more of the shape required for this type of list, and the indentation required for first and subsequent paragraphs in each item. (Also of course you can then make that the default layout for `description` and not need the option at all within the document.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{The first}
  \begin{itemize}[label=, leftmargin=0mm,]
  \item Some text here over fifth lines\ldots{} bla blah
  \end{itemize}

\item \textbf{The second}
  \begin{itemize}[label=, leftmargin=0mm]
  \item Other text here over multiple lines\ldots{} bla blablaaah
  \end{itemize}

\item \ldots

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]